# Basic Android problems

Tags: android, android-studio

I am new to Android Development. I just started learning Android. I have a very simple android code. On the click of a button I want to display some log text. My code is as follows for MainActivity.java file

```
package com.amit.amitapps;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public void clickFunction(View view){
        Log.i("Info", "button Tapped");
    }


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
}
```

And through the properties panel of Button. I have assigned function to button through onClick property. But when I run this code and click on button, my applications stops and gives me an error as `Unfortunately, Amit Apps has stopped`

My XML File:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.ayush.myfirstandroidapp.MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World!"
        android:id="@+id/textView" />

    <Button
        android:text="Button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_marginTop="53dp"
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_bright"
        android:onClick="clickFunction (MainActivity)" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Anyone can help me??

Comment: post the logcat details , always

Comment: better use findViewById and setOnClickListener, this is more transparent way

Comment: @Amit Mhaske post your logcat or xml file

Comment: Just posted XML code... please have a look

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the onclick on your xml file has to be set like this:

```
android:onClick="clickFunction"
```

Comment: Thanks a lot... that actually solved the problem... but hey can you please tell me why `"clickFunction (MainActivity)"` this code didn't work; so I can mark this question as Answered

Comment: you just need to put the name of the method, check here: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html#onClick